# Mother Cat Attacking 3 Weeks Old Kittens

Tags: cats, behavior

My pet cat has two kitten, each 3 weeks old. Suddenly I'm noticing it sometimes bites and scratches the kittens with legs when making "meow" like sound.

Is it normal? Is the cat only attacking the kittens playfully or to teach?

Comment: In what kind o situation does the mother do this? Are the kittens nursing or moving around or doing something else at that moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found out later that it was for teaching to fight. Sometimes it may get a little rough, but mother cat is always careful not to harm the kittens. Kittens sometimes not that careful but they don't have the ability to harm mother cat that much.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question :) Can you add where you found this information out - it might improve your answer even more!